# How to use shell_exec xampp php in a Mac

Tags: php, macos, osx-yosemite

I just cant figure it out how can execute shell commands on php. it must suppose to echo the parameters of mogrify but it always return false. How could i do it on a macbook pro yosemite? i already tried editing all users permissions to read/write/execute but still no luck.. already tried researching the web about this and cant get the answer.

my code is:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("/opt/ImageMagick/bin/mogrify");
?>
```

Comment: are you sure /opt/ImageMagick/bin/mogrify is an existing file ?

Comment: yes i just copy paste what "which mogrify" has returned.

Comment: btw in fact shell_exec does not return `false`, it only return the function result or `null` so you should `var_dump` it instead of `echo`

Comment: var_dump returns nothing.

Comment: `var_dump(shell_exec("/opt/ImageMagick/bin/mogrify"));` returns nothing ? ... wow that's just ... not possible ^^ `null` or the return of the console :/ Can you try to shell_exec `'ls -a'`

Comment: That's very strange, surely rights you was right, but I don't understand where ... if you chmoded 777 ... :/ try with [`passthru($cmd, $returnCode)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)

Comment: Oh c'mon, is your safemode activated ? See in [`shell_exec()` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) : *This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.*

Comment: i'am not using safemode. tried chaning httpd settings to authenticate with my user account still not working. even the user is root.

Comment: using mamp ? xampp ? other ?

Comment: mmhhh, can you try : `shell_exec('whoami');`, if this not running try with exec, just to see which user is used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK for all of you to solve this kind of problem that any terminal application don't run on mac and returns null in any kind of calling terminal apps like shell_exec, exec, system etc. this is the one of a kind that took me 24 hours to know.. it's about the working dir.

```
// The Code that took me 24 Hours to Discover.
exec('unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ;');
putenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH');
putenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin');
$voila = shell_exec("anything you want to execute!");
var_dump($voila);
```

with that work around your problem will be fixed.