# Mac web server with root privileges?

Tags: php, macos, web-services

I would like to execute php scripts that contain the shell_exec() command on my web server, on my mac, but I think I need to change some permissions somewhere to do this.  What permissions do I have to change, and where are they?

Answer (score 0):

```
exec('unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ;');
putenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH');
putenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin');
$voila = shell_exec("anything you want to execute!");
var_dump($voila);
```

- [How to use shell_exec xampp php in a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549181/how-to-use-shell-exec-xampp-php-in-a-mac#30559447)

Comment: Have you tried specifying the entire path to the command you want to run? (e.g. /usr/bin/myapp)